# Убрать тег <a>, оставив его содержимое

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть переменная в которой хранится такой текст:

```
всем привет <h4>это я</h4> и это мой сайт:
<a href="mysite.com" target="_blank">mysite.com</a>
```

как можно из этого текста сделать такой текст:

```
всем привет <h4>это я</h4> и это мой сайт: mysite.com
```

то есть мне нужно убрать HTML код ссылки при этом оставив сам текст ссылки не затрагивая другие HTML тэги, спасибо

Comment: @Visman там говорилось только про ссылки, а тут есть еще и другие тэги, которые надо сохранить

Comment: и зачем все это сунуть в переменную и потом убрать ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить такой фрагмент

```js
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
var parent = element.parentNode;
while (element.firstChild)
  parent.insertBefore(element.firstChild, element);
parent.removeChild(element);
```

```html
<a href="google.com">ссылка</a> на сайт удалена
```

Comment: Вроде работает. Сделано не через регулярки. Интересно, за что минус-то?

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что код работает с `document`, а не с произвольной строкой.

Answer (score -1):

При условии валидности вашего html в переменной можно воспользоваться регуляркой для удаления открывающего/закрывающего тега `a`:

```js
var text = "всем привет <h4>это я</h4> и это мой сайт:\n\
<a href=\"mysite.com\" target=\"_blank\">mysite.com</a> и <a href=\"mysite2.com\" target=\"_blank\">mysite2.com</a>";
text = text.replace(/<a[^>]*>|<\/a>/ig, '');
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
var s = 'всем привет <h4>это я</h4> и это мой сайт:\n\
 <a href="mysite.com" target="_blank">mysite.com</a>';

$("body").html(s).find("a").replaceWith(function () {
  return $(this).html();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А что-нибудь кроме кода?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тут и так всё понятно. Но если очень хочется, можешь написать собственный ответ.

Comment: Сейчас на странице три ответа, которые непонятно чем отличаются. И к тому же показываются в случайном порядке...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, и ни один из них автору не подошёл, потому что он хочет получить строку, а не dom-элементы. Самое время написать ещё один. А случайный порядок - это не страшно - они все независимые и разные :)

Comment: @Qwertiy самое время оформить *одним* нормальным ответом

Answer (score -2):

```js
var s = 'всем привет <h4>это я</h4> и это мой сайт:\n\
 <a href="mysite.com" target="_blank">mysite.com</a>';

var els = $.parseHTML(s).map(function (x) {
  return x.tagName === 'A' ? document.createTextNode(x.textContent) : x
});

$("body").append(els);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо, ваш ответ мне практически подошёл, но дело в том что у меня есть функция, в которую поступает текст, потом текст идёт в переменную, и после обработки, функция возвращает эту переменную, я пробовал вставить ваш код, даже немного поигрался, у меня одни ошибки в консоле, подскажите как его под функцию адаптировать?